# How to create a dynamic pivot table with MySQL/MariaDB and LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, pivot-table, mariadb, libreoffice-calc

I found the following video which might be what I want:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUyZYV6vV1c

I have a MariaDB in localhost, with Ubuntu. I would normally use Excel, but need to use LibreOffice Calc because of Ubuntu, and it is free. 
I need to create simple pivot charts of one SQL query, and to be able to update it by refreshing the pivot after the database is updated.

I found how to import the .jar in the video, but cannot find the option to connect to the database and write the query and link it to a pivot table/chart. How can I do this? Is it possible? If not, is there a free way to get a similar functionality in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Insert -> Pivot Table` and specify `Data source registered in LibreOffice`.  This will show a dialog to set up the database connection.

[image: insert pivot table]

Once the pivot table is created, the data may be updated by right clicking and selecting `Refresh`.

[image: refresh]